# Missing formfield in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to use formsets in Django but encounter a problem I don't understand. The error I get is

```
 [{'id': ['This field is required.']}, {}]
```

Here is the background: In models.py I have

```
class Ledighet(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Personal,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

In forms.py I have the single line

```
LedighetFormset =  inlineformset_factory(Personal,Ledighet,fields =  ('start_date', 'end_date'),extra=1)
```

In views.py I have

```
def rapportera_ledighet(request,person_id):
     person = get_object_or_404(Personal,id = person_id)

     if request.method == 'POST':
          formset = LedighetFormset(request.POST,instance=person)
          if formset.is_valid():
               formset.save()

     formset = LedighetFormset(instance=person)
     context={'person' : person, 'formset' : formset}
     return render(request, 'schema/rapportera_ledighet.html', context)
```

and the key code in the html-file is

```
 <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      <table class="table table-striped">
      {% for f in formset %}
       <tr><td>{{ f.start_date }}</td><td>{{ f.end_date}}</td><td>{{ f.fraction }}</td><td>{{ f.typ }}</td></tr>
       {% endfor %}
       </table>
       <input type="submit" value="Updatera" />
 </form>
```

The form looks the way I want it to be, but I get the error above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried the first suggestion below, but it made no difference. But I do not understand why this happens. When I print out what I get in return it looks good, except that it starts with <tr><td colspan="2"><ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>(Hidden field id) This field is required.</li></ul></td></tr>. Where does that come from?

Comment: The problem was solved by inserting       ` {% for hidden in f.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }}  {% endfor %} ` in the HTML-file. No idea why

Answer (score 0):

```
inlineformset_factory
```

uses `modelformset_factory()`
which is expects a ModelForm

change your `Ledighet` form to a model form like

```
class Ledighet(ModelForm):
  ...
```

and it should work..

you could also try to just add an `id` field to your current form class

see here for model forms
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)